# `autodetect': No known ORM was detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

Unable to clean data using `database_cleaner.rb`; throwing the following issue on running tests.

> /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:147:in
>   `autodetect': No known ORM was detected!  Is ActiveRecord, DataMapper,
>   Sequel, MongoMapper, Mongoid, Moped, or CouchPotato, Redis or Ohm
>   loaded? (DatabaseCleaner::NoORMDetected)

[image]

**spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false


  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.color = true

  Selenium::Application.reload_routes!

end
```

**database_cleaner.rb**

```
require 'database_cleaner'

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: checkout this blog to configure Database Cleaner http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

Comment: Have you defined a model?

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue on controller_spec. 
`'autodetect': No known ORM was detected!  Is ActiveRecord, DataMapper, Sequel, MongoMapper, Mongoid, Moped, or CouchPotato, Redis or Ohm loaded? (DatabaseCleaner::NoORMDetected)`

I resolved by requiring rails_helper file on controller spec.

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

In rails_helper.rb require file 'database_cleaner'.

```
require 'database_cleaner'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue (on Rails 5.1) and the reason was that I had

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

in my `spec_helper.rb`.

I put `require 'database_cleaner` in `spec_helper.rb` as well.

So eventually I moved both things to `rails_helper.rb` and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use my setup, seems to work fine for RDBMS (checked on MySQL and Postgres), put it into your `database_cleaner.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  # this may be needed for Capybara tests and for testing after_commit hooks
  config.before(:each, strategy: :truncation) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

If you want to use `truncation` strategy, just use 
`describe 'something', strategy: :truncation` or `it 'something', strategy: truncation`.